# Not able to click on element which class is same on hover

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have below html where I have to hover first element.
There are three element with same class name. There is no unique identifier.

Here is my html code for element.

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="nav-link nav-toggle">
                    <i class="icon-briefcase"></i>
                    <span class="title">Tender</span>
                    <span class="arrow open"></span>
                    <span class="selected"></span>
                </a>
```

I have tried below code which click on first element which is I want to hover

```
List<WebElement> MainMenu=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[@class='nav-link nav-toggle']"));           
        Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        action.moveToElement(MainMenu.get(0)).build().perform();
```

But there are four element after hovering whose class also same. No unique identifier.

I tried below code

```
List<WebElement> MainMenu1=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[@class='nav-link nav-toggle']"));
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
            action.moveToElement(MainMenu.get(0)).build().click();
```

But not able to click on second element.

My screen is as below
1.[image: first screen where i have to hover]

[image: second screen after first hover]

[image: final click on slighting option]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="ng-scope" data-ng-app="MetronicApp" lang="en">
<head>
<body class="page-header-fixed page-sidebar-closed-hide-logo ng-scope page-content-white page-sidebar-closed" ng-controller="AppController" ng-class="{'page-content-white': settings.layout.pageContentWhite,'page-container-bg-solid': settings.layout.pageBodySolid, 'page-sidebar-closed': settings.layout.pageSidebarClosed}">
<div class="page-spinner-bar hide" ng-spinner-bar="">
<div class="page-header navbar navbar-fixed-top ng-scope" data-ng-include="'tpl/header.html'" data-ng-controller="HeaderController" style="">
<div class="clearfix"> </div>
<div class="page-container">
<div class="page-sidebar-wrapper ng-scope" data-ng-include="'tpl/sidebar.html'" data-ng-controller="SidebarController" style="">
<div class="page-sidebar navbar-collapse collapse ng-scope" ng-show="roleId">
<ul class="page-sidebar-menu page-sidebar-menu-closed" data-keep-expanded="false" data-auto-scroll="true" data-slide-speed="200" ng-class="{'page-sidebar-menu-closed': settings.layout.pageSidebarClosed}" style="">
<li class="nav-item ng-scope" ng-if="roleId != 3 && roleId != 5 && roleId !=7">
<a class="nav-link nav-toggle" href="javascript:;">
<ul class="sub-menu adj_submenu">
</li>
<li class="nav-item ng-scope" ng-if="roleId == 2 || roleId == 6 || roleId == 1">
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<div class="page-content-wrapper" ng-class="(global_user_name != undefined) ? 'page-content-wrapper' : 'page-content'">
<a class="page-quick-sidebar-toggler" href="javascript:;">
<div class="page-quick-sidebar-wrapper ng-scope" data-ng-include="'tpl/quick-sidebar.html'" data-ng-controller="QuickSidebarController" style="">
</div>
<div class="page-footer ng-scope" data-ng-include="'tpl/footer.html'" data-ng-controller="FooterController" style="">
<script src="../assets/global/plugins/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="../assets/global/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="../assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-hover-dropdown/bootstrap-hover-dropdown.min.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="../assets/global/plugins/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="../assets/global/plugins/jquery.blockui.min.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="../assets/global/plugins/js.cookie.min.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="../assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-switch/js/bootstrap-switch.min.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="../assets/global/plugins/angularjs/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="../assets/global/plugins/angularjs/angular-sanitize.min.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="../assets/global/plugins/angularjs/angular-touch.min.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="../assets/global/scripts/angular-animate.min.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="../assets/global/scripts/toaster.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="../assets/global/plugins/angularjs/plugins/angular-ui-router.min.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="../assets/global/plugins/angularjs/plugins/ocLazyLoad.min.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="../assets/global/plugins/angularjs/plugins/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="js/main.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="js/directives.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="../assets/global/scripts/app.min.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="../assets/layouts/layout/scripts/layout.min.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="../assets/layouts/global/scripts/quick-sidebar.min.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="../assets/layouts/global/scripts/quick-nav.min.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="../app/masters/commonServices/commonService.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="../app/lib/ng-file-upload.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="../app/lib/ng-file-upload-shim.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="../app/lib/d3.min.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="../app/lib/nv.d3.min.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="../app/lib/angular-nvd3.min.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="../app/tender/commonTenderController/commonTender.controller.js" type="text/javascript">
<div id="toast-container" class="toast-top-right" ng-class="[config.position, config.animation]" toaster-options="{'close-button':false, 'time-out':{ 'toast-warning': 2000, 'toast-error': 0 } }"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is it possible 2 capture d full HTML for "Tender" menu and put it here ? My guess is tht u'll see parts of the HTML greyed out. Those sections will change certain attributes on hover action. If thr r no unique elements then u'd hv 2 write a slight convoluted xpath like `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[@class='nameCol' and text()='"
                    +name+"']/following-sibling::td/a"))`. As about hovering over & clicking, it might b easier 2 identify d element and chnge attribute with smthing like

Comment: `final JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver; js.executeScript("document.getElementById('id').nextElementSibling.style.display='block';");`.... where display=block is the changed attributed name for element with Id 'id' when it is clickable. There are other, of course, ways of identifying elements on DOM using javascript.

Comment: @user2611581 please check html of tender

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verify once whether the below xpath for Tender is correct.

```
//span[contains(text(),'Tender')]/ancestor::a[@class='nav-link nav-toggle']
```

If yes, then check in html structure whether RPF is immediate child of Tender. If yes then this xpath should work

```
//(span[contains(text(),'Tender')]/ancestor::a[@class='nav-link nav-toggle'])/a
or
//a[text()[normalize-space()= 'RPF']]"
```

If these two xpath work then your final code would be

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
WebElement tender = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Tender')]/ancestor::a[@class='nav-link nav-toggle']"));
WebElement rpf= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//(span[contains(text(),'Tender')]/ancestor::a[@class='nav-link nav-toggle'])/a"));
WebElement sighting = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()[normalize-space()= 'Sighting']]"));
action.moveToElement(tender).moveToElement(rpf).moveToElement(sighting).click().build().perform();
```

I am able to get above two element i.e tender and rfp but I am not able to find last one sighting.

Comment: No but I have to hover first and then click on element both element which is hovering and click are same name. Please see attached screenshot which will clear your confusion

Comment: So you want to click on sighting list?

Comment: I want click on sighting.

Comment: Before that i have to hover mouse on first icon "tender" later i have to click on RFP and finally I need to click on slighting. I have to take elemets in LIST for click on "tender" because there are same class name for other icon. Also once I found "tender" which I am able to find with action.moveToElement(MainMenu.get(0)).build().perform(); By holding this element I have to click on RFP. whoes class name is also same . You and rest of the option below RFP i.e EOI,Emplanment,Private having same class name

Comment: I have edited my reply, please check if those xpath and code work. In case xpath does not work then share html code screenshot from Tender to Sighting to check its hierarchy

Comment: Have you tried it @ShivajiGhadge? Let me know if you are still having issue. In case my reply worked in your case then please mark it as correct.

Comment: Yes the x path was incorrect. I have corrected it and it is working now. Thanks

Comment: That's great. If my xpath worked in your case then please tick my reply as correct or you can edit my reply and add the xpath which worked so that it be beneficial for other who follows this post

Answer (score 0):

```
Tender: //span[text()='Tender']

RFP: //i[contains(text(),'RFP']

Sighting: //i[text()=' Sighting ']
```

Use these to move to the elements and click on sighting.